# Conflicting types for input variables? Are my functions being used properly?

Tags: c, variables, types

Compiler is telling me that I have conflicting types by my definition for the function 'input_instructions"? I have type double for all of the variables. I am new to this so most likely I am doing it wrong and this code is probably awful. If my functions are incorrect can you tell me why. I am not sure how to localize the variables within functions an in main if you know what I mean. Do no have enough context already to post a question. Come on now.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void input_instructions(double *vf, double *vi);
double compute_acc(double vf, double vi);

int main()
{
    double vf,vi,t,a;

    input_instructions(&vf,&vi);

    a=compute_acc(vf,vi);

    t = (vf - vi)/a;

    printf("The constant acceleration of the cyclist is %.2f and it will take him %.2f minutes/seconds/"
            "to come to rest with an initial velocity of 10mi/hr.\n", a, t);
}

void input_instructions(double vf, double vi)
{
    printf("This program will calculate the rate of accleration and the time it takes/"
            "the cyclist to come to rest\n");
    printf("Enter final velocity=>");
    scanf("%lf", &vf);
    printf("Enter final velocity");
    scanf("%lf", &vi);
}

double compute_acc(double vf, double vi)
{
    int t = 1;
    double a;
    a = (vf-vi)/t;
    return (a);
}
```

It keeps telling me to add more detail so i'm just going to keep typing until i can submit my question. Apparently my post is too much code and not enough context but I think you get the idea.

Comment: Should I be using different variables in main than I do when declaring and defining my functions?

Answer (score 0):

input_instructions(&vf,&vi); 
The &vf and &vi  is address
you should use pointer type

This is you function declaration: 
void input_instructions(double *vf, double *vi);

but the function body is : 
void input_instructions(double vf, double vi){...};

Comment: so the function body should be the same as the declaration (double *vf, double *vi)?

Comment: when you declaration the function "input_instructuins(double * vf, double * vi)"  the parameters is pointer, but the function body's paratemers is "double".  The "double * " and "double " are different.

Comment: I changed it but nothing happened.

Comment: OK, change the function body "input_instructuins(double vf, double vi){...}" to "input_instructuins(double *vf, double *vi)"